# Angular 2 Mobile Gestures Block Vertical Scroll

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, hammer.js, angular2-services

Mobile gestures blocks vertical scroll on the page.

For example I have the below div:

```
<div (swipeleft)="onSwipeLeft()" (swiperight)="onSwipeRight()">
contents....
</div>
```

When I swipe left or swipe right, its works properly, but has a problem with the pages that have long contents it doesn't allows vertical scroll on such pages.

Comment: What does *"has problem"* mean? Give a [mcve].

Comment: It doesn't allow vertical scroll, as an example just add above div in your app component and add some contents long enough that request user to scroll the page. Then test it in any mobile device.

Comment: I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because hammerjs swiping is built on top of CSS "**touch-action**" property, which is not supported by iOS. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-touch-action

Update: You can fix this problem by going into the hammer.js file, and making some slight modifications. Comment out the following two code blocks that are near lines 1262 and 1307 respectively.

First this one...

```
if (this.manager.session.prevented) {
  srcEvent.preventDefault();
  return;
}
```

Then comment out the **body** of this function.

```
preventSrc: function(srcEvent) {
  this.manager.session.prevented = true;
  srcEvent.preventDefault();
}
```

Rebuild your app then change your main html file to point at this new modified hammer file.

Comment: The behavior is same with Android.